# Trying to adapt my view to big and small screens through Scroll View

Tags: android, android-layout, scrollview

this is my problem: i'm trying to adapt my view to both big and small screen. as the content doesn't fit a small screen, i thought of using a Scroll View to fix it. it works as i wish on the small screen, but i get an error every time i try to run it on a big screen. my layout code:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout 
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/drawer_layout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:padding="5dp"
    android:background="#ffffff" >

    <FrameLayout
        android:id="@+id/content_frame2"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:orientation="vertical" >

            <com.google.android.gms.ads.AdView
                xmlns:ads="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
                android:id="@+id/adView"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                ads:adUnitId="ca-app-pub-7098126077977688/3494300657"
                ads:adSize="BANNER"
                android:layout_gravity="center"/>

            <ScrollView 
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content">

                <LinearLayout
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:orientation="vertical" >

                    <ImageView 
                        android:id="@+id/ad_view_photo_image"
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_gravity="center"/>

                    <TextView
                        android:id="@+id/ad_view_description"
                        android:text="TextView"
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:padding="5dp"
                        android:layout_gravity="center" />

                    <TextView
                        android:id="@+id/ad_view_price"
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:text="Large Text"
                        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge"
                        android:padding="5dp"
                        android:layout_gravity="center" />

                    <Button
                        android:id="@+id/ad_view_buy"
                        android:text="Comprar"
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:padding="5dp"
                        android:layout_gravity="center" />

                    <Button
                        android:id="@+id/ad_view_back"
                        android:text="Voltar"
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:padding="5dp"
                        android:layout_gravity="center" />

                </LinearLayout>

            </ScrollView>

        </LinearLayout>

    </FrameLayout>

    <include layout="@layout/drawer"/>

</android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout>
```

and the error:

Activity has leaked window

can anybody give me some help? thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

well, i've just solved the problem, it was an issue in my async task that for some reason didn't occur while testing the app within my small screen emulator. i was trying to modify a view created by the main thread in the async task.